# NSExpression respect a subquery NSPredicate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsexpression

Assume that I have 2 entities, a `Person` and a `Transaction`.

`Person` have a to-many relationship with `Transaction` and `Transaction` entity has `amount` and `date`. My goal was to have a `NSFetchRequest` based on the `Person`, but I only want to know persons who have transactions between certain dates and the `SUM` of the transactions amount.

My code looks like:

```
NSExpression *amountKeyPath = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"transactions.amount"];
NSExpression *sumAmountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[amountKeyPath]];

// Create the expression description for that expression.
NSExpressionDescription *description = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[description setName:@"sum"];
[description setExpression:sumAmountExpression];
[description setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

// Create the sum amount fetch request,
self.sumAmountFetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(transactions, $t, $t.date >= %@ AND $t.date <= %@).@count > 0", self.startDate, self.endDate];
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"name", description];
```

Everything seems fine but... When I looked at the SQL Query generated, it looks like:

```
SELECT t0.ZPERSONID, t0.ZNAME, 
    (SELECT TOTAL(t2.ZAMOUNT) FROM ZTRANSACTION t2 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t2.ZPERSON) ) 
FROM ZPERSON t0 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_PK) FROM ZTRANSACTION t1 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.ZPERSON AND (( t1.ZDATE >= ? AND  t1.ZDATE <= ?))) ) > ?
```

So, it seems that the `NSExpression` declared, doesnt respect the `NSPredicate` of the fetchRequest created.

Would that be possible to make the expression also respect the predicate attached to the fetchRequest? Or since `NSExpression` stands by itself, I should attach another predicate to it?

Comment: The SQLite statement looks good to me. The predicate is transformed to the last "WHERE" and that applies to the whole statement. Do you get the expected result?

Comment: No, I got the amount of transactions belong to that person (not limited to the time frame -- WHERE clause)

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean, and my above comment is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont have anything to back my own answer, but after struggling with this for hours. I thought that its not that the `NSExpression` not respecting the fetchRequest's `NSPredicate` but its more to the fact that the predicate of the fetchRequest is a subquery.

```
SELECT t0.ZPERSONID, t0.ZNAME, 
    (SELECT TOTAL(t2.ZAMOUNT) FROM ZTRANSACTION t2 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t2.ZPERSON) ) 
FROM ZPERSON t0 
WHERE 
     (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_PK) FROM ZTRANSACTION t1 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.ZPERSON AND (( t1.ZDATE >= ? AND  t1.ZDATE <= ?))) ) > ?
```

So, the subquery in the predicate is not really transformed into the `WHERE` clause I want. I think if it was creating a `JOIN` instead, that'd work.

My solution in the end is to work the other way around. If I create the fetchRequest from `Transaction` instead, that work perfectly.

```
NSExpression *amountKeyPath = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];
NSExpression *sumAmountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[amountKeyPath]];

// Create the expression description for that expression.
NSExpressionDescription *description = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[description setName:@"sum"];
[description setExpression:sumAmountExpression];
[description setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

// Create the sum amount fetch request,
self.sumAmountFetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Transaction"];
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date <= %@", self.startDate, self.endDate];
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"person.name", description];
self.sumAmountFetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"person.name"];
```

That works perfectly. It has to be grouped by the `"person.name"` so that it would use the `sum:` as wanted.

The SQL generated would be

```
SELECT  t1.ZPERSONID, total( t0.ZAMOUNT) 
FROM ZTRANSACTION t0 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ZPERSON t1 ON t0.ZPERSON = t1.Z_PK 
WHERE ( t0.ZDATE >= ? AND  t0.ZDATE <= ?) GROUP BY  t1.ZPERSONID
```

Cheers,